# jQuery events with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I'm having trouble with jQuery events. What I'm trying to do is when I hover over p element- function fireHover should run, but function fireOver should start running even if first function hasn't finished.

my jQuery:

```
function fireHover() {
    var eventTimeout;
    clearTimeout(eventTimeout);

    $(this).hide();
    $('.opening').removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.opening').addClass('hidden');
    }, 1000);
    clearTimeout(eventTimeout);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.open').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 1000);
    clearTimeout(eventTimeout);
}

function fireOver() {
    var eventTimeout;
    clearTimeout(eventTimeout);

    $(this).addClass('hidden');
    $('.closing').removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.closing').addClass('hidden');
    }, 1000);
    clearTimeout(eventTimeout);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.closed').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.closed').css('display', 'block');
    }, 1000);
    clearTimeout(eventTimeout);
}

$('.wrap .closed').on('mouseover', fireHover);
$('.wrap .open').on('mouseleave', fireOver);
```

Here is what I got so far:

http://codepen.io/rolandas/pen/ogpPYR?editors=101

Comment: To use setTimeout and clearTimeout you need to store the result of setTimeout in the var: `eventTimeout = setTimeout(function () {...}` and that var needs to be in global scope. You then also need to not clear it right after you set it. If you need more than one timeout to run, you need more than one var

Comment: @Satpal your example stops on "opening". Must be something wrong with eventTimeout, can't figure it out..